# understanding laravel memcached settings

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4

Recently I've looked into caching data with laravel and discovered the huge potential in it. I did some research and it turns out that memcached is highly recommended for that very task. I tried looking for information about how I can use it.

I do understand that the API stays the same which is awesome but when looking at `app/config/cache.php` there is a config for memcached:

```
'memcached' => array(

    array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),

),
```

I tried to figure out what is it but with no success.

Moreover, I noticed that it has a `host` property which is set to localhost by default(127.0.0.1) so I was wondering what do I need to set that property if I store my website on a shared host and what it should be set when storing the website on VPS.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need memcache running somewhere. You better check with your shared host to see if they offer it. On the VPS you should be able to install it. So it depends where it is.

Comment: @lagbox and on localhost? using 127.0.0.1 with the port 11211 is suffice? and what exactly the `weight` is?

Comment: @kfirba I've never heard of a shared host having memcached as an option. They'd give you the IP and port.

Comment: @ceejayoz I see. What is the `weight` property?

Comment: you can distribute every memcached request over a pool of servers. With the weight you can define the relative importance/weight of the servers. So a server nstance with a higher ratio receives more requests.